# Query Feature and Usage based entitlements license

Tags: api, licenses

I need to query programmatically the Feature license and usage-based license which is available in UI. Could someone please highlight if we can query the same or is it available in UI only, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Feature licenses** cannot be queried or pulled using API at this time. There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003bFWQAY) around this today

**Usage-Based Entitlements** can be queried with the help of below query:

```
SELECT AmountUsed,CurrentAmountAllowed,Frequency,IsPersistentResource,UsageDate FROM TenantUsageEntitlement
```

NOTE: We cannot query the Name field from TenantUsageEntitlement object. It is not available to query.

1> Setup --> Company Settings --> Company Information

a> Feature Licenses ( Status, Total Licenses , Used Licenses)

b> Usage-Based Entitlements ( Frequency, Allowance, Amount Used)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see that we can get the count of used flow user feature license using below SOQL:
Select count() From User where UserPermissionsInteractionUser=true and isActive=true
Is there any way we can get the count of total flow user feature license?